# Spatialite - get geometry from WKB

Tags: spatialite, well-known-binary

I have a table of WKB HexString values, of the form:

`01010000000812368FA5D106C01C25B4DAE5AE4A40`

in a column called 'Centroid' in spatialite

I want to create a geometry from these values. When I run:

`select GeomFromWKB(x'01010000000812368FA5D106C01C25B4DAE5AE4A40');`

I get a valid geometry. However, if I run:

`select GeomFromWKB('x'||"'"||Centroid||"'") from table;`

I get invalid geometries. It seems that it is impossible to insert these hex values as binary values. I think may be due to Sqlite thinking that the bracked value in the second statement is a string literal and not being able to transform it into a blob/binary literal.

Does anyone have any solutions either within spatialite itself or using a third party library in python or something?

Note that I have also tried:

`select GeomFromEWKB(Centroid) from table;`

I seem to recall doing this successfully before in PostGIS, but I'd rather use spatialite if possible.

Comment: As you probably already realized, what you have in your 'Centroid" column is a *hex* representation of the WKB blob. The function GeomFromWKB is expecting the blob, and not the string hex representation. I don't see any obvious way to revert from the string representation back to a binary blob.

Comment: I looked for hours for an opposite of the SQLite function Hex() to no avail. Strange

Comment: It looks like this python function might be close to what you are trying to do:  [binascii - Convert between binary and ASCII](http://docs.python.org/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Spatialite.
If the string is for example '0x0101000000081236FFF5D106C01C25B4DEE5AE4A40'

```
SELECT CastToBlob(replace('0x0101000000081236FFF5D106C01C25B4DEE5AE4A40','0x',''),1) AS x FROM table    
SELECT CastToBlob(replace([WKBhexAStextDUMPfromSOMEdbColumn],'0x',''),1) AS x FROM table
```